# powershell 5.1, make a switch parameter mandatory with value $true if another switch parameter is present

Tags: powershell

to make it simple, I need to have a function which behave as `ConvertTo-SecureString` regarding the `-AsPlainText` and `-Force` parameters: if `-AsPlainText` is present, `-Force` is mandatory **and** it must **not** be specified as `-Force:$false`

I tried this

```
function test {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='set1')]
    Param( 
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='set1')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='set2')]
        [string]$String,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='set2')]
        [switch]$AsPlainText,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='set2', Mandatory=$true)]
        [switch]$Force
    )

    process { } 
}
```

but if I omit `-Force` Powershell ask for it as a mandatory value instead of raising an exception and if use `-Force:$false`, powershell is happy and does not complain in any way.

is this feasable with Parameter attributes or does my only hope live in code/script verification once in the function?

Comment: You can't express that directly in the param block. Do `if ($AsPlainText -and -not $Force){ throw 'Cannot use -AsPlainText without -Force'}` in the `begin` block.

Comment: If $AsPlainText requires -Force why not just eliminate -Force as a parameter and in the code if $AsPlainTest.IsPresent then the command using -Force  sets -Force:$True ??? Seems to me that there is no need to cause an error condition, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @RetiredGeek this is for the very same reason that ```ConvertTo-SecureString``` request ```-Force``` when ```-AsPlainText``` is used: add a safeguard by forcing the user to add a second switch so he can not say that he was not concious/ aware of what he was requesting